# Understanding lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

Please excuse my simple brain, but I'm having trouble getting my head around Haskell, in particular lists. I have tried to write a function to return all the substrings of a specified length,  n, ( this will decrease by one each time the function is called starting at length of the original string - 1) of a string (without importing modules). I wrote the following code

```
allSubs :: Int -> Int -> String -> [String]
allSubs x n s
    |n > x      = (take n (drop x (tail s))) : allSubs (x+1) n s
```

I am not expecting help with logic or robustness of my code, no matter how flawed. But I'd like to know if any list is even being created. I have only previously coded in C, where I could just type

```
else { return listx }
```

or something, but in this case what would the name of the list be? and if I wanted to use that list in another function, for example if I wanted to find a repeated string in the list using a function findRep I could write

```
    |otherwise  = findRep list
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your function is supposed to return all substrings of a string, shouldn't it take just one argument (the string itself)? What are the first two arguments (`x` and `n`) of your `allSubs` function supposed to be?

Comment: My intention is that this is going to be a small function of a larger program which returns the longest repeated substring of a string. X will start at 0, n will be length of the string - 1, then -2 etc.

Comment: Are you using `ghci`? Just invoke your function with some test values. Or compile and run this one-liner: `main = print $ allSubs 3 4 "humma"` Of course, you have to complete the definition of your function by supplying code for the `othewise` case.

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: But I'm still stuck on what exactly should go in that otherwise case. Where is the list of substrings? I've only previously coded in C, where I could just write return listx  or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually:

```
all substrings of (x:xs) = (all substrings beginning at position 0) ++ 
                           (all substrings of xs)
```

so there are two functions involved: "all substrings of" and "all substrings beginning at position 0". Let's call them `allsubs` and `pos0`.

Now consider how you would define `pos0` recursively:

- for the empty string the only substring beginning at position 0 is the empty string
- for `(x:xs)` we can either have the empty string or let `ys` be a member of `pos0 xs` and prepend `x` to it

Now you just have to translate this specification to Haskell.

Putting it all together:

```
allsubs "" = ???
allsubs (x:xs) = pos0 (x:xs) ++ allsubs xs

pos0 "" = ???
pos0 (x:xs) = [ "" ] ++ ???
```

Comment: Although, your solution may be for more efficient and effective.